# Using Karma, how do I exclude all files that match a pattern except for those within a specific sub-folder?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a simple AngularJs application setup, that looks a bit like this:

```
client
    vendor
        angular
        bootstrap
        jquery
        ...
    app.module.js
    app.controller.js
    ...
node_modules
    angular-mocks
    ...
```

I'm setting up a `karma.conf.js` file and I want to include `angular\angular.js` from `vendor`. I don't want to include anything else from `vendor`.

Here is what I have in the relevant `karma.conf.js` sections:

```
files: [
    'client/vendor/angular/angular.js',
    'client/**/*.js',
    'client/**/*.spec.js'
],
exclude: [
    'client/vendor/**/*.js'
],
```

The problem I have is simple: I'm including `angular.js` explicitly in `files`, but it is then being excluded in the `exclude` section pattern.

How can I exclude all of `client/vendor` except for `angular/angular.js` (and perhaps others later)? The `client` directory contains a lot of files, sub-folders, etc, that include my own .js files, so it's not easy to just move everything I want to include into a folder of its own, for example.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
client/vendor/**/!(angular).js
```

[Example](http://www.globtester.com/#p=eJzT19LSV9RIzEsvzUks0tTLKgYAKAwFGg%3D%3D&r=eJxNy9ENgCAMBcBVDAP4FkC2cIAKDWoKJFRIdHr5Mv7f2XD0yQupLibR5XfjsCpXRSiR0bneoEQPz6daDOzsbwzctEKKJ8F2ZFCOTah%2B%2BAVCeyFp&)

More filenames can be excluded like this:

```
client/vendor/**/!(angular|angular-route).js
```

The patterns used here are called [globs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29).

Here is a short [guide](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer) to glob functionality in node from `node-globs` on GH.

Comment: That's pretty much got it. The next problem I had was that both angular.js and angular.min.js were being included, so I just changed it to !(angular.js), which seems to have done the trick. Thanks for the links also - very useful.

Comment: That works but will apply to all file extensions, and not just `.js` files. The simplest way to do that is `!(angular*).js`, which would also match any angular modules etc.

Comment: This in `files` or `exclude`? For clarity sake

Comment: @Z.Khullah It's been a while since your comment, but the change was made in `exclude`.